# Can we use constraint name of a primary key as foreign key reference?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

For example, I'm creating two tables as shown below:

```
create table A (
  department_id int,
  college_id int,
  constraint Pk_name primary key(department_id,college_id)
);

create table B (
  student_name varchar(75),
  department_id int,
  college_id int,
  foreign key(department_id,college_id) references A(Pk_name)
);
```

Can I write like this?

Comment: I'm using  Mysql Workbench 8. I tried this but it gives error. The error is :  "Failed to add foreign key. Missing column 'Pk_name' for constraint."

Comment: As far as I know, no database supports such an extension.

Comment: I don't know any database that supports that. Though it doesn't look like a bad idea, it can be confusing when the database grows and ends up having many tables. Also, pretty much no one name the PK constraints. Sometimes UNIQUE constraints have more visible names than PK ones. Besides, how will the engine differentiate between columns and constraint names? Probably the syntax will end up being more verbose than the one you are showing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so because there's no way that the RDBMS  could know whether `PK_name` is a column or a constraint name so I suggest if you stick with the usual :

`create table A (
  department_id int,
  college_id int,
  constraint Pk_name primary key(department_id,college_id)
);`

create table B (
  student_name varchar(75),
  department_id int,
  college_id int,
  foreign key(department_id,college_id) references A(department_id,college_id)
);

I will update the answer once I find an other answer .

Comment: Thanks for your replying to my question. If you find the answers, please update them. Thank You.

Comment: Very good point @anouaressayid. In any case, the syntax should clearly differentiate the "column case" vs the "contraint name case".